# Regex: split a complex list (two columns) in Java

Tags: java, regex, file, readline

I'm trying to figure out how to split a file (two columns) to **readLine();** by considering a lot of delimiters (see bellow).

Here are all possibilities of my delimiters (see comments)

```
+--------+---------+
+ ##some text      + //some text which starts with (##) I want to exclude this row
+ 341,     222     + //comma delimited
+ 211      321     + //space delimited
+ 541      1231    + //tab delimited
+ ##some text      + //some text which starts with (##) I want to exclude this row
+ 11.3     321.11  + //double values delimited by tab
+ 331.3    33.11   + //double values delimited by space
+ 231.3,   33.1    + //double values delimited by comma
+ ##some text      + //some text which starts with (##) I want to exclude this row
+--------+---------+
```

I want to obtain this table:

```
+--------+---------+
+ 341        222   + 
+ 211        321   +
+ 541        1231  +
+ 11.3      321.11 +
+ 331.3     33.11  +
+ 231.3      33.1  +
+--------+---------+
```

I will be glad to find a solution to this issue

UPDATE:

For now I have **([,\s\t;])+** (for comma, tab, space, semicolon...) but I can't figure out how to do for ##some text. I tried \##\w+ but didn't work. Any advice?

Comment: This is not a split, it's a replace.

Comment: The number of spaces in you desired output keeps varying. Is this intentional? The regex `(\d+)\D+(\d+)` will match only the desired rows and capture the numbers btw.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Simon Andre Forsberg Yes, I just know how to use \\s+ /t , . Belive me, I made some surfing.

Comment: For now I have this `([\b.##,\\s\\t;^])+` but the output says `java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String`. I think that the `##word` matches, but remains an empty string. Someone have an idea?

Comment: try `##[a-z\s]+` for the comment lines

Comment: I get: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` array is empty. Can I fix it?
By the way, the regex seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...
I have tried it and its working fine.

`(\\d+\\.?\\d*),?\\s*?(\\d+\\.?\\d*)`

and replace with `$1` and `$2`.

EDIT:

TRY BELOW CODE...

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class regcheck
{
    private static Pattern twopart = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.?\\d*),?\\s*?(\\d+\\.?\\d*)");

    public static void checkString(String s)
    {
        Matcher m = twopart.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1) +" " + m.group(2));
        } else {
            System.out.println(s + " does not match.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Parts of strings are ");
        checkString("##some text");
        checkString("123,     4567");
        checkString("123,   342");
        checkString("45.45   4.3");
        checkString("3.78,  23.78");

  }  
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
Parts of strings are
##some text does not match.
123 4567
123 342
45.45 4.3
3.78 23.78
```

`m.group(1)` will give you the first part.
`m.group(2)` will give you the second part.

In your code use `checkstring()` method for single line....

Comment: I'm confusing where to put $1 and $2.
I use the regex to split something. My actual regex is `String pair[] = s.split("([,\\s\\t;^])+");` (I tried to add `##[a-z\\s]+|([,\\s\\t;^])+` which @garyh suggested me, but I got `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 array is empty`.

Comment: I have found some code...
try to put my given regular expression in pattern..
here it is http://stackoverflow.com/a/3483070/513340

Comment: Thanks Sir, I don't forget you :).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ASCII isn't part of the input, you could try this:

```
##[a-z\s]+|([\d\.]+)[,\s\t]+([\d\.]+)
```

then replace with:

```
\1   \2     (or $1    $2)
```

Note, this doesn't allow for commas in the numbers